# Can't submit the form after validating with jquery

Tags: jquery

I had this code. The script returns true, on ajax success but it doesn't return this value to the function, so the form can't be submitted.
Please anyone can help?

UPDATE:
I modified the script:

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addForm').live('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".error").remove();
        var client_name = $("#client_name").val();
        var project_name = $('#project_name').val();
        var source_lang = $('#source_lang option:selected').length;
        var job_no = $('#job_no').val();
        var targ_lang = $('#targ_lang option:selected').length;
        var supplier_id = $('supplier_id option:selected').length;
        var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
        var deadline = $('#deadline').val();
        var targ_lang_val = $('#targ_lang option:selected').val();
        var source_lang_val = $('#source_lang option:selected').val();
        var haserror = false;
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : 'json',
            async : false,
            url : "file.php?job=" + job_no + "&client_name=" + client_name + "&project_name=" + project_name + "&source_lang=" + source_lang + "&targ_lang=" + targ_lang + "&supplier_id=" + supplier_id + "&start_date=" + start_date + "&deadline=" + deadline + "&targ_lang_val=" + targ_lang_val + "&source_lang_val=" + source_lang_val,
            success : function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    if (index == 'job_no') {
                        if (element == true) {
                            $("#" + index).after('<br><span class="error" style="color: red;">This Job No already exists.</span><br>');
                            haserror = true;
                        } else
                            haserror = false;
                    }
                    if (element == true) {
                        $("#" + index).after('<br><span class="error" style="color: red;">This field is required.</span><br>');
                        haserror = true;
                    } else
                        haserror = false;
                });
                return !haserror;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The server side **PHP Code**:

```
$client_name = $_GET['client_name'];
$deadline    = $_GET['deadline'];
if ($client_name == '') {
    $hasError['client_name'] = true;
} else
    $hasError['client_name'] = false;
// .........................
if ($deadline == '') {
    $hasError['deadline'] = true;
} else
    $hasError['deadline'] = false;
print json_encode($hasError);
```

Comment: FYI: [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of version 1.7

Comment: Two problems: you are returning a result before your `check()` method completes because AJAX calls are asynchronous. For the same reason, `err_job` will always be `false`. Secondly, double check this logic: `!(hasError && err_job)`. This is equivalent to `(!hasError || !err_job)`. I think you might want `!(hasError || err_job)` instead.

Comment: understand, thank you, but how can i modify the code to get the correct returned value?

Comment: @rakela: Because you want to control the submission of the form based on the result of a call to the server, I think you're going to have to instruct your `$.ajax` usage to be *synchronous* (add `async: false` to its options). And if I may suggest: I would simply omit this check from happening client-side. You should be doing additional server-side validation anyway (**never** rely on client-side-only validation), at which time you can check for a duplicate job number.

Comment: I updated the script (edited the question), please take a look. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: will you share your full html code and php code..?

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
return !haserror;
```

with

```
if(!haserror) $('#addForm')[0].submit()
```

direct call to submit method of `DOM` element `FORM` does not fire the `submit` event

(here the fiddle as example http://jsfiddle.net/kKXa7/ )